# How to pick up where it left during the download of SMS message logs from Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

I know that to download SMS messages we do this:

```
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var messages = MessageResource.Read();

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
    }
```

I am downloading a good amount of messages. This operation might take up to 12 hours. Now if anything happened within the foreach loop, I have to restart the process.

I am wondering what I can do so that the program can resume the download process should any error happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update a variable within the loop to save the DateSent value of the latest message you have processed.

If an error is thrown you can supply the DateSent as a list filter in your next request to the Twilio API and it will only return message on/before/after that date.

> Only show messages sent on this date (in GMT format), given as
>   YYYY-MM-DD. Example: DateSent=2009-07-06. You can also specify
>   inequality, such as DateSent<=YYYY-MM-DD for messages that were sent
>   on or before midnight on a date, and DateSent>=YYYY-MM-DD for messages
>   sent on or after midnight on a date.

I think the API also returns paging information, so you could do something similar using that.

Either way you would probably still get a few duplicates around the point of failure so you would need to be saving each message Sid somewhere so you can filter those out too.